# Using links to static and non-static methods with interface

Tags: java, lambda

Why I can call **non-static** method `length()` from class `String`, but I can't call **non-static** method `lengthHelper( String line )` from my class `ExpressionHelper`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] lines1 = {"H", "HH", "HHH"};
    System.out.println(sum(lines1, String::length));
    System.out.println(sum(lines1, s -> s.length()));
    System.out.println(sum(lines1, ExpressionHelper::lengthHelper)); //wrong
}

interface Expression {
    int length(String line);
}

static class ExpressionHelper {

    int lengthHelper(String line) {
        return line.length();
    }
}

private static int sum(String[] lines, Expression func) {
    int result = 0;
    for (String i : lines) {
        result += func.length(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `String::length` is an instance method of String. It requires an instance of String to run, which you are providing. `ExpressionHelper::lengthHelper` is an instance method of ExpressionHelper. It requires an instance of ExpressionHelper to run, which you are not providing.

Comment: @user16320675 – When you rephrase the question and looking onto the issue from a different angle, you may be right. But the topic itself is confusing enough for a rookie that I think we should answer the question as it was asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String::length` is an instance method of String. It requires an instance of String to run, which you are providing, because you are passing elements of `lines1` to it.

`ExpressionHelper::lengthHelper` is an instance method of ExpressionHelper. In addition to the explicit `String line` argument, it requires an instance of ExpressionHelper to run, which you are not providing.

If you made `lengthHelper` a static method in ExpressionHelper, then you would be able to call it without an instance of ExpressionHelper.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [the answer from khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71510609/1554195):

If you change your code like this:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{
    final var expressionHelper = new ExpressionHelper();
    String[] lines1 = {"H", "HH", "HHH"};
    System.out.println(sum( lines1, String::length ) );
    System.out.println(sum( lines1, s -> s.length() ) );
    System.out.println(sum( lines1, ExpressionHelper::lengthHelper) ); //wrong
    System.out.println(sum( lines1, expressionHelper::lengthHelper) );
}
```

it works also with `ExpressionHelper::lengthHelper` (although I should write better `ExpressionHelper.lengthHelper()` or `ExpressionHelper#lengthHelper` to avoid further confusion …)

Yes, I know, in this context it is nasty to name the variable same as the class, only having the first letter as lower case: it does not support readability.

But now `expressionHelper` is that instance of `ExpressionHelper` that @khelwood mentioned as missing in their answer.